# ActiveAdmin and Formstastic, 3 drop down select menus from the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, formtastic

I have a model called Shipments, that has string data type columns: place_of_origin, place_of_loading, place_of_delivery.

I have another model called Places that has names of cities in them.

So in the NEW Shipment page I want to create a drop down select menu for place of origin, place of loading and place_of_delivery. And those 3 select menus are supposed to pull their information from the Places table.

I already tried different combinations of code but I can't figure it out http://rubydoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/master/Formtastic/Inputs/SelectInput

I have used `collection => Places.all` but it prints something like #<0xPlaces00000> I know I'm close but can't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 2):

So, if Places is a model with a field 'name,' you would use the following syntax:

```
:collection => Places.all.map(&:name).uniq
```

This will do two things, it will build an array of all of the 'names' of Places, and it will make sure it is a unique array (remove duplicate items).

So basically whatever column from Places you want to be in the select box, put that in place of 'name' in the map call.